# Why would Field::preSave not be called?

Tags: 8, entities

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\custom_widget\Plugin\Field\FieldType\TaxonomyPriorityField
 */

namespace Drupal\custom_widget\Plugin\Field\FieldType;

use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemBase;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldStorageDefinitionInterface;
use Drupal\Core\TypedData\DataDefinition;
use Drupal\Core\Field\Annotation\FieldType;
use Drupal\Core\Annotation\Translation;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface;

/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'custom' field type.
 *
 * @FieldType(
 *   id = "taxonomywidget",
 *   label = @Translation("Taxonomy widget"),
 *   description = @Translation("custom field"),
 *   default_widget = "customwidget",
 *   default_formatter = "custom_formatter"
 * )
 */

class CustomField extends FieldItemBase{

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function schema(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition) {
    return array(
        'columns' => array(
            'field1' => array(
                'description' => 'One term from the vocabulary Category',
                'type' => 'text',
                'size' => 'medium',
                'not null' => TRUE,
            ),
            'field2' => array(
                'description' => 'An integer between 1 and 999',
                'type' => 'int',
                'size' => 'normal',
                'not null' => TRUE,
            ),
        ),
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function propertyDefinitions(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition) {
    $properties = [];
    $properties['field1'] = DataDefinition::create('any')
    ->setLabel(t('Category'));
    $properties['field2'] = DataDefinition::create('any')
    ->setLabel(t('Field2'));
    return $properties;
  }

  public function preSave(){

    /*some code here*/
    file_put_contents(DRUPAL_ROOT.'/logs/module.log', 'presave is executed');
  }


}
```

I am using the above code  in a field. But no code in there is being executed.    and I have no idea why.  Everything else in my field works except that presave function

Comment: I think function preSave() working ok. You can use **Logger** to check it. Example 

`public function preSave(){
    \Drupal::logger('my_module')->notice('presave is executed');
  }
`


and goto admin/reports/dblog see log.

Comment: You have a field, not an entity. Field presave is only called if you have values in your field.